# Selenium HtmlUnitDriver not clicking on button

Tags: java, button, selenium, webdriver

I want to click on the button:

```
<input type="submit" value="Stock!" class="button" tabindex="5" />
```

Here is my code:

```
    WebElement stock = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"stock\"]/table/tbody/tr[4]/td/input[5]"));
    stock.click();
```

The program runs without throwing any errors, but the button is not being clicked, and the program is not completing its task.

Comment: Can someone clarify why this question is put on hold? I believe this has all required information, the code and the issue.. is something else missing?

Answer (score 1):

Try using SendKeys instead of Click. Although it looks strange, it has worked for me in many times.

```
stock.sendKeys(Keys.ENTER);
```

Or you can do this very simply as shown below. This will automatically submit the values in the particular form where the element is present. Life made easy.

```
stock.submit();
```

Not necessarirly you should use the input (type=submit) for the submit() action. You can use any other element in the html form.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the \" and replace it with '.  However, you don't actually have an id attribute so that isn't going to work.

Try:
"//input[@tabindex='5']"

If the tab index is actually set there should only be one that has 5 in there.  If there is more than one for some reason you can use the full xpath, but it is really not a good idea to utilize the entire xpath with numbered indexes.  If anything changes these might break easily.

Answer (score 0):

You can use cssselector, which looks very clean to read.

```
WebElement stock = driver.findElement(By.CssSelector("input[value = 'Stock!']")).Click();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

driver.findElement(By.className("button")).click();